# How to make an element in ul lists unsortable and undraggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

An ul list contains some items. The last item must always stay in a static position. I've tried to use `cancel` option of the `.sortable()` method, but it doesn't switch off sortable, just dragging.

```
<ul id="sort">
    <li>Jquery</li>
    <li>MooTools</li>
    <li>Prototype</li>
    <li>YUI</li>
    <li class="last">must stay static (add position button)</li>
</ul>

$('#sort').sortable({
    cancel: '.last'
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbarinov/JLZvY/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items) options to specify a selector which excludes items that expose the `last` class:

```
$('#sort').sortable({
    items: "li:not(.last)"
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JLZvY/1/).